# AWS SSM ERROR IN WINDOWS MACHINE

Tags: amazon-web-services

The Amazon SSM Agent service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 512 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 30000 milliseconds: Restart the service.